# Disallowing one more than click on a button

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to remove an event from the document after one click:

```
var allow=true;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    if(allow){
       x = e.pageX;
       y = e.pageY;     
       var offTop = y-10;
       var offLeft = x-25;      
       $('iframe').offset({ top: offTop, left: offLeft });
       $('body').on('click',iFrame,function(){
               console.log('I was clicked');
       });
    }
});

$(document).click(function() {
   allow=false;
   $('iframe').remove();
});
```

I want to remove the iframe that follows the mouse after the first click on the document.

But my code doesnt seem to work..why?

```
UPDATE:
```

Is there to trap a mouse click without relation to any element..e.g. without this $('document').click()//// but any click that was clicked on the left mouse button.. ?

Comment: **related to your edit:** you could bind the click event to `window` But it's still unclear after all what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ecamot/2/edit)*

It's cause your mouse pointer in **OVER** the iframe all the time!
Use: e.g: `y+25;` and `x+25;`

```
if(allow){
   x = e.pageX;
   y = e.pageY;

   var offTop = y+25;
   var offLeft = x+25;      
   $('iframe').offset({ top: offTop, left: offLeft });
}
```

Comment: yeah, but i did ..but that is not what screws it

Comment: see update..is there a way to trap any click even and delete the iframe after there is a click event?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd you should really explain a bit more: What second click? What are you trying to achieve, have you tried my code and what exactly is not satisfying you!

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd ok tell me... you really want the cursor to BE over the iframe? cause I gave you a good example. And extra tweak would be to check if the iframe is visible to prevent the code extra runs if there's no need to (no document clicks if iframe is hidden).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var allow=true;

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    if(allow){
        x = e.pageX;
        y = e.pageY;
        var offTop = y-10;
        var offLeft = x-25;      
        $('iframe').offset({ top: offTop, left: offLeft });
    }    
}); // THIS WAS MISSING

$(document).click(function() {
    allow=false;
    $('iframe').remove();
});
```